# Unable to compile TypeScript of symlinked package using babel-loader

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I have 2 packages: 'shared' and 'web'. They both use TypeScript. I'm using webpack with babel-loader in 'web'. When I symlink 'shared', it's unable to compile its TypeScript.

This issue suggests using `symlinks: false` in webpack.config.js, but doesn't work:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1643

### Folder structure:

```
root
│
└───shared
│   │   package.json
│   │   UseMe.ts
│   
└───web
    │   .babelrc
    │   index.ts
    │   package.json
    │   tsconfig.json
    │   webpack.config.js
```

shared\package.json

```
{
  "name": "shared",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.6.4"
  }
}
```

shared\UseMe.ts

```
class UseMe {
    prop: string
}

export default UseMe;
```

web\.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ]
}
```

web\index.ts

```
import UseMe from 'shared/UseMe';
const x = new UseMe();
```

web\package.json

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

web\tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
  }
}
```

web\webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
        symlinks: false
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|js|tsx)?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

### Commands:

```
cd shared
npm install
npm link
cd ..\web
npm install
npm link shared
npm run build
```

### Error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/shared/UseMe.ts 2:8
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| class UseMe {
>     prop: string
| }
|
```

Comment: Does installing and adding `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` as plugin to `.babelrc` help?

Comment: @ford04 Good thought, I tried your suggestion but it didn't fix it. Even if I remove the property and just change the `class` to `interface` it's still not able to compile the `.ts` file. So doesn't look like it's due to the property.

Comment: You'll also want to have a look at [babel mono repo configs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#project-wide-configuration) `babel.config.js`, as babel transformations with `.babelrc` stop at a package root indicated by `package.json`. And when you have `symlinks: false`, I would expect babel to ignore transformations of your linked packages, as you have set `exclude: /node_modules/` for `babel-loader`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

1. Delete `root\web\.babelrc` and replace it with `root\web\babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);

    const presets = ["@babel/preset-typescript"];
    const plugins = [];

    return {
        presets,
        plugins
    };
}
```

2. Remove line `exclude: /node_modules/` from `root\web\webpack.config.js`

### More Information

The first problem was that when using Babel, `.babelrc` limits its scope to the the same folder as `package.json`. So even if I manually moved the 'shared' folder into `root\web` it still wouldn't work, unless I deleted `shared\package.json`.

The second problem was that when a package is symlinked, it winds up in your 'node_module', therefore `exclude: /node_modules/` would exclude it from its transpiling.

See this page for more information: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files

Thanks to @ford04 for coming up with the answer, I just wrote up the steps.